# View US version of Amazon wish list from localized version

Tags: amazon

Someone has a Japanese Amazon wish list but I'd like to view the US (English) version of it. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try simply changing the URL from `amazon.co.jp` to `amazon.com`?

Comment: Yes, that gives a not found error. There's also a button to change the language to English, but most text is still in Japanese. And I don't have an account on the Japanese Amazon. I think they are separate websites.